# Polynomial Solution

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If we have this polynomial:
P($x$) = $x^3$ - $3x^2$ - 10$x$ + 24
and we want to find the root b:
P(b) = 0
in the book, the solution is that b must be a factor of 24, **why is that**?
I couldn't find an explanation for this.

[book solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMZhg.png)

Comment: $b(b^{2}-3b-10)=-24$ and $b$ divides LHS

Comment: $P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) =$ something $-abc$ and $-abc = 24$. Can you see why the existence of a complex root is not a problem?

Comment: @Majd FYI, somewhat more generally, see the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: An *integer* root of the equation must be a factor of $24$. As John Omielan points out, this is a consequence of the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).